# Entering Content Into A MySQL Database Via A Form

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been working on creating a form that submits content into my database but I decided that rather than using a drop down menu to select the date I'd rather use a textfield. I was wondering what changes I will need to make to my table creation file.

```
<?php mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
mysql_select_db ('tmlblog');

$sql = "CREATE TABLE php_blog (
  id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  timestamp int(20) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  entry longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't create the table 'php_blog' in the database.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

mysql_close();
if ($result != false) {
    echo "Table 'php_blog' was successfully created.";
}
?>
```

It's the timestamp that I need to edit to enter in via a textfield. The Title and Entry are currently being entered via that method anyway.

**Whenever I use my form to update the database I get the following error message:**

Can't insert into table php_blog.
INSERT INTO php_blog (time_stamp,title,entry,) VALUES ('1270140960','kjkkj','jkjkjk')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('1270140960','kjkkj','jkjkjk')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIMESTAMP is a reserved MySQL word. You will need to place backticks around it if you wish to use it as a field name. However, I recommend changing it.

You should also make it a DATE or DATETIME field as that's the kind of data you're actually storing in it.

Comment: I used this method but despite that fact I'm constantly getting the same error message:

Can't insert into table php_blog.
INSERT INTO php_blog (datestamp,title,entry,) VALUES ('1270140480','gdg','dffdfdfd')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('1270140480','gdg','dffdfdfd')' at line 1

Comment: You have an extra comma after entry.

Comment: @webbiedave That has nothing to do with my. I've set it so that if there is any error with the posting to the database it generates the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have to make any changes to that part of your script. What you would need is to retrieve the users date input through a text input in your form and convert it (if its in valid format) to a timestamp.

Edit: unless of course you really want the timestamp to be a date in string or date format then you'd have to change int to varchar(9) (to contain xxxx-xx-xx or whatever format you prefer) or use date or datetime

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the MySQL standard DATETIME type for this.  Get the textfield's content for a date and feed it to PHP's [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions to get it into a format that matches what MySQL is looking for in a DATETIME object.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Read the manual pages for strtotime and date.  It's all pretty much laid out there.  Read in the value from the text field, pass it to strtotime to get a php timestamp, feed that timestamp to date with a formatting string similar to what MySQL is expecting (pretty sure YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS works) and then save that value to the database with an UPDATE or INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to modify anything. Just make sure you correctly parse the input from the user and create a timestamp with [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Comment: I've tried using the form after creating this table but i get the following error message:
Can't insert into table php_blog.
INSERT INTO php_blog (timestamp,title,entry,) VALUES ('1270138860','ggg','ggg')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('1270138860','test','test')' at line 1

Comment: Well, timestamp is too small (choose 32 bits) and (not sure, I am not a mysql user), it might be a reserved name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter the current time stamp into the `time_stamp` field every time a row is being inserted you can change its definition to:

```
time_stamp  TIMESTAMP NOIT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

this way you need not do an explicit insert for `time_stamp` field.

**EDIT:**

If you want to edit the field from the form you can use the above def of time_stamp field and include the `time_stamp` value while doing the `insert`. It should be in the format:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

Note: `timestamp` is a MySQL reserved word. I've renamed it to `time_stamp`.

Comment: If by this you mean that I wouldn't need to edit it via a form, I'd much rather have the ability to edit via my form.

Comment: Could you explain this to me. I'm not the best at coding so I don't understand most of the "technobabble".